# Aplicar CSS quando estiver no menu em questão

Tags: jquery, css

Eu gostaria de deixar um item selecionado quando eu estiver em algum menu selecionado.
Por exemplo, se eu estiver no link '/sobre'. 
O item do menu chamado 'sobre' deve mudar de cor, por exemplo. Teria como fazer isso?

Comment: Sim. Adicione a classe dinamicamente com base no `window.location`

Comment: Você pode realizar isso de acordo com o `window.location` e o `window.location.href` se você não conseguir assim avise aqui que quando der posto algo para você.

Answer (score 2):

Basta você adicionar uma classe de CSS e aplicá-la quando clica no elemento ou ler o url para saber onde está

Um exemplo:

HTML

```
<div class="menu" data-url="sobre">Sobre a empresa</div>
```

CSS

```
.selected {
    color: #aac;
}
```

jQuery

```
var url = document.URL.split('/');
// em vez do document.URL pode usar também window.location.href ou window.location.pathname
url = url[url.length - 1] || url[url.length - 2];
console.log(url); // aqui vai dar-lhe o url em que está
$('.menu').each(function () {
    var self = $(this);
    if (self.data('url') == url) {
        self.addClass('selected');
        return;
    }
    self.removeClass('selected');
});
```

No HTML juntei um campo "[data-field](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/)". Assim pode guardar, no elemento, qual o nome a que deve reagir. Dei-lhes também uma classe `menu` para facilitar o selector jQuery que vai procurar esses elementos do menu.

No CSS criei uma classe chamada `selected` com uma côr específica.

No jQuery vou primeiro ler o URL. Deixei uma redundancia para o caso de url que acaba com `/`. Mas de resto, como mostrou no seu exemplo num url como `www.dominio.com/sobre` ele vai apanhar o `sobre`. 
Depois comparo todos os elementos do menu para saber qual o que tem `data-url="sobre"` e esse vai receber a classe nova. Os outros removo-lhes a classe caso a tenham desde antes (improvável se você muda de página).

**Nota:** devo dizer que isto é bem mais limpo quando feito do lado do servidor. Nesse caso basta adicionar a classe certa ao elemento correspondente à página que vai abrir. Mas presumo não lhe ser possivel isso.

Comment: Muito obrigado por sua excelente resposta, meu amigo. Só tenho mais uma dúvida. Eu tenho esse html http://jsfiddle.net/felipestoker/Vm7bG/  o `data-url` eu usaria aonde, no caso? no `topoMenuLista`?

Comment: @FelipeStoker pode colocar também o JavaScript da página. Presumo que queira abrir o drop-down respectivo também.