# Pegar link da URL e modificar CSS

Tags: jquery, css

Eu gostaria de pegar o link da URL e com isso, modificar a propriedade da classe `flechaSubmenu` de `display:none` para `display:block`.
Eu pensei em fazer com CSS:

```
.classe a[href^="/categoria/categoria2/"] {
    display:block;
}
```

O que acontece, é que o link teria que estar em uma **div** que não é o caso.

Resumindo, eu quero que a uma flecha do meu site, aponte para o Menu atual de onde eu estiver.

Meu HTML:

```
<li>
    <a href="/pt/page/investidores">
        <span>Investidores</span>
        <div class="flechaSubmenu"></div>
    </a>
</li>
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div.flechaSubMenu[href='/pt/page/investidores']").addClass("flechaI");
});
```

CSS:

```
.flechaI {display: block!important;}
```

Comment: Ainda não percebí o que procuras. Queres adicionar uma classe de CSS quando o URL é o mesmo que o `href` ? ou somente a um `href` específico que tens numa string?

Comment: Por exemplo, quando a URL for igual a **/pt/page/investidores** a **div** `flechaSubMenu` deve ficar `display:block` (ou adicionar aquela classe que criei)

Comment: tenho essa `<div class="flechaSubmenu"></div>` em várias `li`, mas quero que ela fique ativa conforme a URL em questão.

Comment: Ok, então queres ler o url da página e dar `class="flechaSubmenu"` á div que tem a ancora com esse `href` correto?

Comment: Exato, olha como está meu HTML oficial do menu que contém essas `li` http://jsfiddle.net/ps1ewtmf/

Comment: Já viste esta outra pergunta que tinhas feito antes: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/22206/129 ?

Comment: Cara, você ta querendo um simples menu com current e está complicando tudo.

Comment: @Rafael não é que estou complicando, é que não tenho muito conhecimento mesmo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando o código que você postou, eu consegui aplicar o `display: block` na `div` com o seguinte **código jQuery**:

```
$( "a[href='/pt/page/investidores']" ).find( ".flechaSubmenu" ).css( "display", "block" );
```

**Explicação:**

- `$("a[href='/pt/page/investidores']")` - vai selecionar todos os links que redirecionem para a página em questão.
- `find(".flechaSubmenu")` - pega os descendentes do link que possuem a classe `flechaSubmenu`.
- `css( "display", "block" )` - aplica a propriedade `display: block;` no elemento selecionado pelo [find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/), dessa maneira você pode dispensar a segunda classe `flechaI`.

Se você quiser utilizar a classe `flechaI` é só alterar o `.css()` por `.removeClass("flechaSubmenu").addClass("flechaI");` ou algo parecido.

Comment: no caso o `flechaSubMenu` vai antes do `a`, certo?

Comment: Nesse caso ele vai aplicar a propriedade `display: block` ao link independente da classe, em outras palavras, ele invalida a propriedade `display: none` e aplica o `display: block;`.

Comment: Tipo isso?
`$("flechaSubMenu a[href='/pt/page/investidores']").css("display", "block");`?

Comment: Faz assim: `$("a.flechaSubMenu[href='/pt/page/investidores']").css("display", "block");`.

Comment: Eu modifiquei a pergunta e coloquei meu HTML + CSS + JQuery, baseado em sua resposta, mas não funcionou.

Comment: Editei a resposta pra solução correta.

Answer (score 0):

Tenta utilizar o código abaixo, não se esquece de importante o jQuery antes desse script.
Não entendi a linha de CSS que da `display:block` para a classe `flechaI` pois não localizei essa classe em seu código, de toda a forma, não aplique nenhum CSS com propriedade `display` para a classe `flechaSubmenu`.

Se eu entendi certo, você quer aplicar isso de acordo com a URL, no caso seria esse código abaixo:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.flechaSubmenu').hide();
  if(window.location.href.indexOf("/categoria/categoria2/") > -1) {
    $('.flechaSubmenu').show();
  }
});
</script>
```

Se você quer validar com o `href` elemento pai `a`, faça isso:

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
   $("a").each(function () {
    if ($("a").attr("href") == "/categoria/categoria2") {
      $(this).find(".flechaSubmenu").show();
    } else {
      $(this).find(".flechaSubmenu").hide();
    }
   });
 });
</script>
```